# "Оправдаться" or "оправдать себя"

Tags: выбор-слова, глаголы

Sometimes I don't know which reflexive form is better.

I know that **оправдаться** means *"to be justified"*.

But, if I want to tell *"I don't need to justify myself"* (in the sense of "I don't need to give excuses", "I don't need to explain why I did such"), should I say "мне не нужно **оправдать себя**"?

Comment: This two meaning another words)

Comment: @JrAa you most probably wanted to say "this two mean different words" but even if so - this is exactly what's the question about, so it's not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense, 'I don't have to explain myself to you', these will work:

- Я не обязан (перед тобой/вами) оправдываться.
- Мне не за что (перед тобой/вами) оправдываться.

A few examples of **оправдаться** (the perfective counterpart of **оправдываться**):

- Сегодня мы оправдались перед болельщиками за прошлые неудачи.
- Политик попытался оправдаться перед избирателями.

Note the use of **перед**.

When used with прогнозы/надежды/расчеты/ожидания, etc. **Оправдаться** means 'to come true':

- Его надежды не оправдались. = His hopes did not materialise.
- Его расчеты не оправдались. ~ He miscalculated. / His expectations turned out to be wrong.
- Он не оправдал наших надежд. ~ He let us down.

You can't (and need not) use **перед** in this sense.

Both **оправдаться** and **оправдать себя** have a third sense, 'to prove itself worthwhile' (normally said of inanimate things):

- Вложенные средства оправдались с лихвой.
- Риск полностью оправдался.

Answer (score 0):

**Оправдываться** is also **to make excuses**.

In the meaning of "I have no need to give excuses" it would be

> **Мне не нужно оправдываться.**
>
> **Мне не в чем оправдываться.** (There's nothing for me to give excuses for)
>
> **Мне не за что оправдываться.** (As previous)

Make use of the reflexive particle -ся, it's helpful.

And **to be justified** can, vice versa, be translated as **быть оправданным**, for example, in a court, where you do not justify yourself, you are just found not guilty.